# Port SPAN similar to MAC flooding?

Tags: mirror, network

I wanted to know if a SPAN port on a switch (which is used to monitor all packets passing through the network) is similar to any other port if a mac flooding attack is performed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really. A SPAN interface is primarily used as a one-way interface; copied traffic goes out. The monitoring equipment on the SPAN interface has no real need to send any traffic into the switch, so there isn't much, if any, traffic that would be redirected from the SPAN interface.

Comment: If i connect a pc to the SPAN port i will not be able to use it as a normal port? For example to browse the internet, upload or download files, etc? (By ... one-way interface ...) Thanks!

Comment: It would not work very well as a normal PC. The interface will be flooded with traffic going out the interface.